# Is it possible to combine a ContourPlot and StreamDensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

This is accepted with StreamPlot, but not with StreamDensityPlot

```
sf = x^2 + 2 y^2 - 2 x y;
gr = Grad[sf, {x, y}]
y1 = y /. Solve[gr[[1]] == 0, y]
y2 = y /. Solve[gr[[2]] == 0, y]
cp = ContourPlot[sf, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[y1 // N], {x, -3, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}];
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[y2 // N], {x, -3, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed, Thick}];
sp = StreamPlot[{gr, sf} // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
sdp = StreamDensityPlot[{gr, sf} // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
Show[cp, sdp, p1, p2]
Show[cp, sp, p1, p2]
```

Following the advice I was able to plot my function, but I still have a problem with PlotLegends, which outputs twice the same thing (on MMA 11.3)

```
    ma = 1/2; as = 2.687;  bs = .464; la = 3 as/2;
Js = (2.3811513130556867` + 4.7623026261113734` a - 
     2.3811513130556867` E^(2.` a) + 
     0.32787828263921914` E^(1.5832456116050557` b) + 
     0.6557565652784383` a E^(1.5832456116050557` b) + 
     5.418059191389812` E^(2.` a + 1.3916228058025277` b) - 
     0.32787828263921914` E^(
      2.` a + 1.5832456116050557` b))/(3.1748684174075827` - 
     0.27759210781469157` E^(2.` a) + 
     0.4371710435189584` E^(1.5832456116050557` b) + 
     1.` E^(2.` a + 1.5832456116050557` b));
gr = Grad[Js, {a, b}];
sdp = StreamDensityPlot[gr, {a, ma, la}, {b, 0, 2 bs}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{a, b}, First@gr], 
    Function[{a, b}, Last@gr], Function[{a, b}, Js]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Yellow}, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, 
      Directive[Red, Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.005]]]}}, {{0, 
      Directive[Directive[Green, Dashed, Thickness[0.005]]]}}, {{4, 
      Directive[Red, Directive[Thickness[Small]]]}, {15/4, 
      Directive[Green, Directive[Thickness[Small]]]}, {7/2, 
      Directive[Blue, Directive[Thickness[Small]]]}, {13/4, 
      Directive[Yellow, Directive[Thickness[Small]]]}, {12/4, 
      Directive[Red, Directive[Thickness[Small]]]}}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Red}, {"4", "15/4", "7/2", 
     "13/4", "3"}, LegendLabel -> J0]]
```

Also, I would like to add a point to the sdp

```
abs = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{as, bs}]}];
```

Comment: Seems to work in MMA 12.1.

Comment: To add a point,just add `Epilog -> {PointSize[.1], Red, Point[{as, bs}]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do all of these  in StreamDensityPlot by using `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions`

```
sf = x^2 + 2 y^2 - 2 x y;
gr = Grad[sf, {x, y}];
newsdp = StreamDensityPlot[gr, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  MeshFunctions -> {
    Function[{x, y}, First@gr],
    Function[{x, y}, Last@gr],
    Function[{x, y}, sf]
    },
  MeshStyle -> {Yellow},
  Mesh -> {
    {{0, Directive[Red, Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.01]]]}},
    {{0, Directive[Directive[Green, Dashed, Thickness[0.01]]]}},
    {
     {5, Directive[Red, Directive[Dotted, Thickness[Large]]]},
     {10, Directive[Blue, Directive[Dotted, Thickness[Large]]]},
     {15, Directive[Pink, Directive[Dotted, Thickness[Large]]]},
     {20, Directive[Purple, Directive[Dotted, Thickness[Large]]]},
     {25, Directive[Cyan, Directive[Dotted, Thickness[Large]]]},
     {30, Directive[Black, Directive[Dotted, Thickness[Large]]]}
     }
    }]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to erase an acolade nad type just just {0, Directive[Red, Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.01]]]}s there a reason that the first two directives are {{0, Directive[Red, Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.01]]]}}  instead of

Answer (score 3):

The [`StreamDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamDensityPlot.html) is covering up and hiding the [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html). In the `ContourPlot`, turn off the [`ContourShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html), color code the contours, and use [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html). Then put the `ContourPlot` on top of the `StreamDensityPlot`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sf = x^2 + 2 y^2 - 2 x y;
gr = Grad[sf, {x, y}];
y1 = y /. Solve[gr[[1]] == 0, y][[1]];
y2 = y /. Solve[gr[[2]] == 0, y][[1]];

cp = ContourPlot[sf, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ContourShading -> None, 
   ContourStyle -> ({Thick, ColorData[97][#]} & /@ Range[8]),
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[8], Range[5, 40, 5], 
     LegendLabel -> SF]];

p1 = Plot[y1, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}];
p2 = Plot[y2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed, Thick}];

sdp = StreamDensityPlot[{gr, sf} // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];

Show[sdp, cp, p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: This  is beautiful, but not easy for non-profesionals! I wonder if some package already provides one automatic command like MAP[scalar field], including the above features, and also isoclines. This could replace eventually the  "classic  contour maps"  in atlases (so much more can be done for  visualizing two dimensional fields than what we are used to from  atlases).

Comment: is 8 a default for Contours, or did you chose it after seeing the first output ?

Comment: What is ColorData[97] ?

Comment: `Options[ContourPlot, Contours]` evaluates to `Automatic`. From the docs for `ContourPlot`, "With Automatic settings, "nice" equally spaced contour levels are chosen, whose values minimize the number of digits in their decimal representation." Since its value is context dependent, I did look at the `ContourPlot`. [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) is how a [`color scheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html) is designated. See the documentation. `97` is the default color scheme for `Plot` so it is one with which I am familiar.